# Traceback (most recent call last): File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module> import django ImportError: No module named 'django'

Tags: django, python-3.x, pip

I tried a lot but after installing python and pip I created virtual environment and installed django but when I am checking django version it is showing:
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import django
ImportError: No module named 'django'**

please tell me what could be the problem:
python version-3.4.0
pip version-8.1.2
django version-1.9

Comment: How are you trying to import it? Please post the code/command that fails.

Comment: You did it in that sequence? : 1. install python and pip 2.create virtual environment 3.activate the environment 4.install django.

Comment: thanks for your quick responce.
yes, first i installed python 3.4,
then pip is already installed with Python 3.4 but that version is very old so i will be using
>> pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: Thanks for responceyes, first I installed python 3.4,
Upgrading pip to latest version
>> **pip install --upgrade pip**
then I will install virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper using below command
>>**pip install virtualenvwrapper-win**
then creating virtual environment using below command
>>**mkvirtualenv myproject**
then I installed django using below command
>>**pip install django**
after this I am trying  to check the django version using below code in Python console
>>import django
>>django.VERSION
then i am getting the error mentioned in title.
thanks in advance.